What is the correct way to compute non-linearity error for output voltage containing a non-linear element like thermistor?

I am taking a course in Advanced Instrumentation and Signal Conditioning this semester. There was a question in the course material as shown in the image attached.
My approach towards solving is as follows:
Method-1

Fitting a linear plot between the extreme temperatures for the thermistor from the given data
Finding the resistance of Thermistor from the equation of plot obtained in the 1st step and calculating the equivalent resistance at T = 50°C, finally leading to the output voltage expected.
This voltage as obtained above is compared with the actual output voltage by taking the actual resistance value of thermistor at 50°C and calculating the equivalent resistance, finally leading to the output voltage.


However I saw a few others solving it the following way:
Method-2

The second method is to get the output voltages corresponding to the actual equivalent resistance at 50°C by fitting a linear plot between the two extreme values of output voltage.
Comparing the obtained value with the actual value to get the error.

Finally computing the non-linearity error as a %age of the Full Scale Reading of output voltage.

So I would like to know which one is the correct approach. The course instructor told that the answer should be same either way, which unfortunately is not the case.

Are you aware that the R/T transfer function of a typical NTC thermistor is an anti-log function, with terms of ln^-1; ln^-3; ln^-5, ...?

This is more a question of language than of electrical engineering:
Method 1 calculates the error versus a hypothetical system (System #1) which contains an ideal linear thermistor. Note that the output transfer function of System #1 is still non-linear because the sum of two parallel resistors is inherently non-linear.
Method 2 calculates the error versus a hypothetical system (System #2) which is an ideal linear temperature sensor.
It's not 100% clear which problem you are being asked to solve. In fact, if your professor says that the two approaches are identical, they may have neglected the fact that System #1 is non-linear even with a linear thermistor. You would be within your rights to bring this to their attention and ask for a clarification.
